# How does this findRoute function work in Chapter 7 of Eloquent Javascript 3rd Edition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In the Chapter 7 of *Eloquent Javascript 3rd Edition*, the author creates a function `findRoute` to find the shortest route between two locations. It's so hard to understand it for beginners like me. Can anybody help explain how it works?

The `roadGraph` is the map data that will be passed to the `findRoute` function as `graph`:

```js
// Places and roads of Meadowfield

const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
];


//function to convert the roads into a data structure

function buildGraph(edges) {

  let graph = Object.create(null);

  function addEdge(from, to) {

    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }

  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }

  return graph;

}

// assign the data structure to roadGraph

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);


// The function that searches the shortest route between two places in roadGraph

function findRoute(graph, from, to) {


  let work = [{
    at: from,
    route: []
  }];


  for (let i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {

    let {
      at,
      route
    } = work[i];

    // I'm especially confused on the following loop
    
    for (let place of graph[at]) {

      if (place == to) return route.concat(place);

      // so confuesd on the following if statement, how does it work at all?
      
      if (!work.some(w => w.at == place)) {
        work.push({
          at: place,
          route: route.concat(place)
        });
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: i don't think this question is for this forum.

Comment: look up [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for a high-level understanding of what the code is doing